# How to install Tomcat 8 ZIP as a Windows XP service?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, inno-setup, tomcat8

I'm creating a **.exe** bundle to install all my projects in the client machine. In order to do that, I have downloaded all projects in **.zip** format, so I can copy it to the bundle (using *Inno Setup*).

The point is that I'm trying to install Tomcat 8 as a service, so I have downloaded it in **zip** format like the other projects. But in every way I've tried to install it as a Windows XP service, it returned the following message:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

When I use a JDK installation it works fine, but I need it to use a JRE installation because all my operation team install features with JRE and we can't change the company patterns in order to do this.

Can someone, please, help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use JRE instead of JDK for Tomcat, you need to set JRE_HOME instead of JAVA_HOME. See [RUNNING.txt](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt)